# selecting from 2 tables query SQL

Tags: sql

Okay hello there I have 2 tables

Route table which has

```
route ID, frequency, start destination, final destination
```

and

Operates table which has

```
Proportion, Operator name, Route ID
```

I need to select Route id and frequency where the operator name is Arriva.

I put this SQL together which works and gets me the result but I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

```
SELECT route_number, frequency
FROM route, operates
WHERE route_ID = route_number
AND operator_name =  'Arriva'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the right way, just that your first where statement is wrong:

```
SELECT route_number, frequency
FROM route, operates
WHERE route_ID = **route_number**
AND operator_name =  'Arriva'
```

It should be route_ID as well (at least from what you said). In order for this to work you need to give names to your tables, so SQL knows which columns you are comparing (since the names are the same from both tables). Like this:

```
SELECT 
    route_number, 
    frequency
FROM 
    route r, 
    operates o
WHERE 
    r.route_ID = o.route_number
    AND o.operator_name =  'Arriva'
```

Comment: Hey thanks all these work. This is an assignment and I am not sure which is the correct way to do it. Even the answer posted by 03Usr works. Not sure if it matters what kind of query I use to complete this :/

Comment: The inner join syntax posted by 03Usr is the same thing, but it's newer and is supposed to be safer. But in this case it's really about what you suits you the best. They are equally right